# Custom page template not showing up when using a pagebuilder theme (mostly Elementor)

Tags: custom-wordpress-pages, elementor, child-theming

I've installed a theme (that i bought) that's mainly made with Elementor.
Since I've been running into some issues with customizing this theme, (and still refuse to also pay money for Elementor Pro) I decided it would be easier to create a custom template myself.
I have done this before when I used a custom theme I made myself from scratch (I thought I was saving myself some time this time around...).

So my problem: I saved this template called page-home.php to my Child theme (that I made of the purchased Theme) in a folder called page templates.
It is not showing in the drop down menu when creating a new page.
I then just copied it to the main theme, activated that...and still not showing.

Is this because the Theme is using a page builder like Elementor?
Or do you think the creator of the theme somehow disabled this option?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Elementor ignores the most of the standard theme file. It does so i.e. with the header.php for sure. The question is what do you want to put in a theme file what you couldn't do with Elementor. Have a look at the
"Hello Theme" https://github.com/elementor/elementor/issues/14283 - it's a plain theme.

If you don't want to pay for Pro, I recommand the plugin "Elementor – Header, Footer & Blocks Template" (and for better editor handling: "Flexible Elementor Panel")